# partitions on an integer with some properties

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n,m,r\in\mathbb N$. How to decide if we have a partition of $n$ in $m$ parts admiting $r$ as a part?

I would like to get a condition on $n,m,r$ to be possible to get this partition and a way to count these partitions.

For intance, by taking $n=5,m=3,r=3$, we have:

- all partitions of $n$ with $m$ parts: $5=3+1+1=2+2+1$.
- all partitions of $n$ with $m$ parts and $r$ as a part: $5=3+1+1$.

For intance, by taking $n=5,m=4,r=4$, we have:

- all partitions of $n$ with $m$ parts: $5=2+1+1+1$.
- all partitions of $n$ with $m$ parts and $r$ as a part: we don't have one.

Comment: Wouldn't this be equivalent to finding out how to partition $n-r$ into $m-1$ parts? For which, there is a well defined procedure to count.

Comment: @PaulLeVan what is this well defined procedure to count?

Comment: It's not an explicit form, which isn't surprising for partitions, but a recursive one. If you want to count the number of ways for a number $n$ to be partitioned into $k$ parts, it is expressed as $p_k(n)=p_k(n-k)+p_{k-1}(n-1)$ with $p_0(0)=1$, and any negatives being zero. That last equality being the recursion. If you're working with small level numbers, it shouldn't be that algorithmically taxing.

Answer (score 1):

**You can** remove $r$ from  $n$ but, you should still be able to distribute the remaining $n-r$ in $m-1$ parts. **You can** perform it only if,

$n-r\geq m-1\implies n+1\geq m+r$

---

**You can** confirm it by putting the values from both examples,

1. $5+1\geq 3+3\implies6\geq 6 $$\ \ \ \ \checkmark$
2. $5+1\geq 4+4\implies6\geq 8 $